# How to do Javascript Function which will change the style display of element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function burgerMenu(){
            //alert(document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display);
            if(document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="none"){
                document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="block";
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="block"){
                document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="none";
            }
    }
```

I want to toggle the burger menu icon. So if I press the icon the burgerMenu() function will be toggle and verify if its display: none then change to display:block and vice versa. hiddenMenuUL is the  for list of  links.
This line below is the button line in HTML:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="burgerMenu()">&#9776;</button>
```

My CSS for hiddenMenuUL

```
#hiddenMenuUL{
        display: none;
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Comment: protip: don't set style properties directly using JS. Instead, have normal CSS classes in a .css file that either show or hide your element, and then toggle those classes using `element.classList.add(...)`, `element.classList.remove(...)` and/or `element.classList.toggle(...)`. See [the docs for .classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for more information.

Comment: `.style` only contains inline styles, it doesn't contain styles that come from CSS. So the first time you call the function, it may not find the style you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing your if, you are not actually checking if the display === "none", you are trying to set it to none.

What you should be doing looks like this:

```
function burgerMenu(){
            let menuStyle = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display;
            if(menuStyle === 'none'){
                document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="block";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display="none";
            }
    }
```

**Edit:**

It seems display rule is defined in CSS, and isn't inline.

.style can only reach inline styles, for example:

```
<div id="hiddenMenuUL" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Adding 'display: none' inline like in the example above should be the fastest and easiest way to 'fix' it in your particular scenario, although it probably wouldn't be considered the best practice.

Comment: It works now but for some reason when I click the first time it goes inside the if statement but doesnt open it with first click, but then if i press again the toggle option works and then if i keeps spamming it opens and closes instantly. Its empty for some reason in  `let menuStyle = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display; ` line

Comment: You should refer to Barmar's comment under your question about .style finding inline styles only. Alternatively you can edit your question and provide the HTML/CSS code, to paint the whole picture.

Comment: like this line of code should be outputting 'None' if i console log it: `let menuStyle = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuUL").style.display;` But instead its empty on the first click

Comment: Yes, it console logs nothing because it can't reach the CSS rule because it is not set inline. After that, if/else sees menuStyle isnt 'none', so it gives hiddenMenuUL an inline display of none, after which everything works as intended. See my edited answer for the quickest way to get past this.

Comment: wow man, thanks it worked. Is there an actual way to reach CSS rule?